# How to best time-profile a TFJS workflow?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have a TFJS webapp that takes in frames from a Video, does some pre-processing, passes it into a TFJS Model (converted from a TF Frozen Model), post-processes output and renders that back to a canvas using custom code written in WebGL.
I am unable to get proper timing splits between Preprocessing (which includes fromPixels), Model Inference Time and Post Processing.
Here are the things that I tried to time the application:

- console.time
- performance.now
- tf.Profile (which gives kernelTimeMs)

None of the above methods gave representative numbers. One thing I noticed is that the Datasync (downloading/uploading of buffers to and from GPU, correct me if I am wrong) call is taking about 90% of the time as compared to the Kernel Operations. I've read in some of the issues that the execute function just assembles/prepares the Kernel according to the TF graph along with the weights and doesn't actually execute them until a Datasync operation is called? Does this lead to the timing discrepancy that I'm noticing?

Kindly help me clarify, thank you!

Comment: Maybe this answer can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853386/problem-measuring-the-time-elapsed-executing-my-code-in-tensorflow-js/57854393#57854393 ?

Comment: @edkeveked Hey, thanks for the reply! I did try out using the techniques listed in the above link, but I'm not getting an accurate timing for the inference. Says about 2-3ms but we know it can't be that low. These techniques don't account into the time taken for datasync. Maybe that's why the significant difference.

Comment: What is your code ? Because I don't see why it won't account for a certain function call